# Unity in 12.04 with vmwgfx (VMWare player 4.0.3)

Tags: unity, vmware

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 in VMware Player 4.0.3.
I have also installed all updates. But when I login to Unity it is not working.
I can see desktop but Dash and Icons are disorted.

I have read that vmwgfx should work on 12.04.
I have Acer Extensa 5220 notebook with intel X3100 graphics card.

Some time ago I have played with Mesa/VMWGFX (compliled from git) and I was able to make 3D work in VMWare.

I suppose a fresh install of Ubuntu will work. As vmwgfx was moved from staging and Mesa is new enough.

Any suggestion what can be wrong?

http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/336/ubuntuunityvmwgfx1.png
http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/6948/ubuntuunityvmwgfx2.png
http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/3113/ubuntuunityvmwgfx3.png

Answer (score 1):

I have Sony Z11 notebook with 2 video cards, Intel & nVidia. VMWare Player+Ubuntu+Unity 3d (compiz) works great on nVidia (faster one), while Intel shows exactly the same symptoms as yours. I haven't got it working on Intel, but this fact shows that the problem might be in the host OS video driver incompatibility with the VMWare Player/Ubuntu guest. Maybe you could try to update host video driver to the latest version.

My system setup:

```
Notebook: Sony VPC-Z1190X
Host OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
Videocard 1: NVidia GeForce GT 330M / Driver 190.24
Videocard 2: Intel GMA HD / Video BIOS 2120.0 / Driver 8.15.10.2021

VMWare: Player 4.0.3
Ubuntu: 12.04 64-bit
Unity/Compiz: latest from repository.
```

Comment: Hello. Now I has been playing with adding ppa:xorg-edgers. So I updated to this ppa, but unity was not working. But I have tried to run glxinfo and it showed that I am running on Gallium on SVGA3D. Next I have tried to run glxgears and it worked perfectly. So I installed tuxracer and it worked. So 3D is working in VMWare. I suspect that this is maybe some problem with unity. Next I will try to install gnome-shell and we will see,

Comment: Now I tried Gnome Shell and as I can say it is working perferctly. So there is some bug in Unity.

Comment: Now I installed OpenArena and it's working !!! On my Acer Extensa 5220 (2.0 Ghz Celeron and Intel X3100 GPU) in VMWare I've got 30FPS. Cool.

Comment: Yup, seems its a problem of Unity vs host graphic drivers. I installed VMWare Workstation 2012 Technology Preview and it has the Gallium SVGA drivers by default. Still no Unity on Intel videocard.